# Angularjs formData.append is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am developing angularjs application. I have file upload module. I am appending file data to FormData as below.

```
 var filesformdata = new FormData();
    angular.forEach(this.pendingFiles, function (value, key) {
                filesformdata.append(key, value);
            });
            for (var pair of filesformdata.entries()) {
                console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
            }
```

This is My angular code.

```
angular.module('RoslpApp').factory('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
    debugger;
    var fileuploadurl = "http://localhost:19144/" + 'api/Customer/UploadLeaseFiles/' + 2;
    var service = {
        uploadUrl: fileuploadurl,
        pendingFiles: [],
        doUpload: doUpload
    };
    return service;


    function doUpload() {
        debugger;
        var filesformdata = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(this.pendingFiles, function (value, key) {
            filesformdata.append(key, value);
        });
        for (var pair of filesformdata.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
        }

        return $http.post(this.uploadUrl, filesformdata, {
            transformRequest: angular.identity,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': undefined
            }
        })
    }
}]);
```

This is directive code.

```
myapp.directive('fileModel', ['fileUpload', function (fileUpload) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind("change", function (evt) {
                fileUpload.pendingFiles[attrs.fileModel] = evt.target.files[0];
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

This is upload function

```
  $scope.upload = function (filename) {
                debugger;
                fileUpload.doUpload().success(function (success) {
                   console.log(success);
                });
            };
```

This is html code.

```
<div class="upload-button" ng-repeat="file in files">
                <div class="upload-button-icon">
                    <img src="images/folder-small.png">
                    <div class="upload-text">{{file}}</div>
                    <input type="file" id="file1" name="file1" file-data="{{file}}" file-model="{{file}}"/>
                </div>
            </div>
   <input type="submit" value="{{ 'NEXT' | translate }}" class="blue-button" ng-click="upload()">
```

Eventough i have files in this.pendingFiles when i display using console.log or in api using below code i dont get files.

```
  System.Web.HttpFileCollection hfc = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
                // CHECK THE FILE COUNT.
                UploadedLeaseFiles totalDocumentInserted = null;
                for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt <= hfc.Count - 1; iCnt++)
```

I have files inside this.pendingFiles. Please see the screen shot. [image: this.pendingFiles contains file data][image: Network tab]

My filesformdata FormData is empty always. May i get some help here to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: While posting it what is shown under the headers section of your Networks tab.If it is there, then the problem is not with formdata appending but elsewhere

Comment: Can you post more code?

Comment: Thank you. I have added more code.

Comment: $scope.files= ["Passport","Visa"]; This is giving problem.  $scope.files= [1, 2, 3]; this works fine

Comment: Are you getting any error for the former case cause I can't seem to find any error in your code?

Comment: Thank you. $scope.files=[1,2,3] works fine but I want to have $scope.files=["visa","passport"]

Answer (score 1):

The data in a FormData object filesformdata is not revealed by inspecting it with console.log(). It is there, you just can't see it. But however you can view it in networks tab under request payload.

Comment: Thank you. I have added screen shot which i captured from network tab. I dont see anything there.

Comment: Is it going inside the success or error part of your http request to the server?

Comment: System.Web.HttpFileCollection hfc = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
                UploadedLeaseFiles totalDocumentInserted = null;
                for (int iCnt = 0; iCnt <= hfc.Count - 1; iCnt++) Here count is 0. That means i am not recieving any files.

Comment: So basically you are not going inside the success of your http request.Then your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah i am getting exception in iCnt <= hfc.Count - 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `filesInput` directive that integrates with the [ngModelController API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController):

```
app.directive("filesInput", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: postLink
  };
  function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
    elem.on("change", function() {
      ngModel.$setViewValue(elem[0].files);
    })
  }
});
```

Usage:

```
<input type=file ng-model="files" files-input multiple />
```

Test it with:

```
  vm.compute = function () {
        var filesformdata = new FormData();
        angular.forEach(vm.files, function (value, key) {
            filesformdata.append(key, value);
        });
        for (var pair of filesformdata.entries()) {
            console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
            console.log(pair[1]);
        }

  }
```

You will find that [formData.append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) works.

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/qpDza8jbqEbpEYv1Hp8T?p=preview)